# Questions about generators

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

I have a problem with understanding the meaning of a group generated by two elements. For example, if $G=<a,b>$ i,e $G$ is a group generated by two elements, does that mean for any $g \in G$, $g$ can be represented as $(ab)^{i}$ where $i \in \mathbb{Z} $?

I know for a group $G=<b>$ means $G=\{b^n:\ n \in \mathbb{Z}\},$ so if $G=<a,b,c>$, does this imply that $G=\{(abc)^n:\ n \in \mathbb{Z} \}$.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

No.  In general,  you get all *reduced words* formed from $a$ and $b$.  That is, any product $a^{i_1}b^{j_1}\cdots a^{i_k}b^{j_k}$.

In case $G$ is abelian,  this simplifies to $a^ib^j$.

Comment: So what about if the group is not abelian? should we consider the cases $b^ia^j$?

Comment: Yes if it is not abelian then we also consider $b^ia^j$, or I guess alternatively you just allow $i = 0$.